# .NET Core Identity Framework and Telegram Login Widget with no database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, telegram, blazor-server-side

I am making a Blazor Server app, which is tied to my Telegram bot. I want to add the ability for the user to login using [Telegram Login Widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login). I have no plans to add login/password authentication and I therefore don't see any reason to use the database to store anything login-related other than the Telegram User ID.

All of the samples imply using the login-password model along with the database, somewhat like this:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Inevitable, this line appears in all of the samples: `services.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();`

Here's my question: how do I *just* put the user's data (after checking the info from Telegram) into app's context, without storing anything in the database? Or if I'm forced to, where do I change the database scheme? Maybe I don't even need to use the Identity framework for this? All I want is for all the pages to have the info about the user, and the authentication happens on Telegram's side, I just get all the info in response and check the hash with my private key. All I want to do after that is put that model into app's context, I'm not even sure I plan on storing the cookie for the user.

To be clear: I already know how to get info from Telegram and check the hash, let's assume after executing some code on a page I already have some `User` model with some filled out fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, this is how I did it. While not ideal, this works for me. However, I'd love to get some clarifications from someone, specifically on `IUserStore` stuff.

1. I've added [Blazored SessionStorage](https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage) as a dependency to the project
2. I've registered my own implementations of `AuthenticationStateProvider`, `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore` in Startup.cs like this:

```cs
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, CustomUserStore>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Role>, CustomRoleStore>();
```

The first line is the most important one. Implementations of `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore` don't really matter, but it seems like I *have to* register them for Identity framework to work, even though I won't use them. All of the methods in my "implementation" are literally just `throw new NotImplementedException();` and it still works, it just needs them to exist for the `UserManager` somewhere deep down, I guess? I'm still a little unclear on that.

3. My `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` looks like this:

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
  private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage;
  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  private readonly AuthenticationState _anonymous = new(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

  public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    ISessionStorageService sessionStorage,
    IConfiguration configuration) : base(loggerFactory)
  {
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    // setting up HMACSHA256 for checking user data from Telegram widget
    ...
  }

  private bool IsAuthDataValid(User user)
  {
    // validating user data with bot token as the secret key
    ...
  }

  public AuthenticationState AuthenticateUser(User user)
  {
    if (!IsAuthDataValid(user))
    {
      return _anonymous;
    }

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FirstName),
      new Claim("Username", user.Username),
      new Claim("Avatar", user.PhotoUrl),
      new Claim("AuthDate", user.AuthDate.ToString()),
    }, "Telegram");
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var authState = new AuthenticationState(principal);
    base.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(authState));
    _sessionStorage.SetItemAsync("user", user);
    return authState;
  }

  public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
  {
    var state = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    if (state.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      return state;
    }

    try
    {
      var user = await _sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<User>("user");
      return AuthenticateUser(user);
    }
    // this happens on pre-render
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
      return _anonymous;
    }
  }

  public void Logout()
  {
    _sessionStorage.RemoveItemAsync("user");
    base.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(_anonymous));
  }

  protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(AuthenticationState authenticationState,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    try
    {
      var user = await _sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<User>("user");
      return user != null && IsAuthDataValid(user);
    }
    // this shouldn't happen, but just in case
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval { get; } = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
}
```

4. In my Login Blazor page I inject the `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` like this:

```cs
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
```

5. And finally, after getting data from the Telegram widget, I call the `AuthenticateUser` method:

```cs
((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).AuthenticateUser(user);
```

Note, that I have to cast `AuthenticationStateProvider` to `CustomAuthenticationStateProvider` to get exactly the same instance as `AuthorizedView` would.

Another important point is that `AuthenticateUser` method contains call to `SessionStorage`, which is available later in the lifecycle of the page, when `OnAfterRender` has completed, so it will throw an exception, if called earlier.